# double issue : lost precision

Tags: hadoop, hive, precision

I have data as below:

```
  241   97,5    143,5   17,5    21  
  203   90      113     8       23
```

I've loaded it to a hive table, and put data type as double but I've lost precision of data

For example 97,5 become 97,0

Perhaps it's a problem with the comma but I cant change my input file.

I've also tried to change the data type to string, it still the same but after I needed sum function it cast it to decimal I think so those values doesn't count at all.